# Probability of Billy being the first triplet called to the desk

Tags: probability

> There are 11 students in a class, three of whom a triplet -- Billy, Annika, and Catherine. The teacher calls all 11 students in random order one at a time to his desk, but Billy is in the bathroom for the first name call and only returns in time for the second student call (Billy cannot be called first). What is the probability that Billy is the first of the triplets to be called to the desk?

I found the probability assuming the restriction that Billy cannot be first was not there. This is simply $$\frac{\binom{11}{3}(2)(8!)}{11!} = \frac{1}{3}$$ as you first choose three out of eleven spots and place Billy in the first out of those three, and you can arrange the other two spots as Annika-Catherine or Catherine-Annika. The rest of the students can then be arranged in 8! ways.

---

For the probability under the restriction that Billy cannot be  the first student called, I thought it would simply be

$$\frac{\binom{11}{3}(2)(8!)-10!}{11!} = \frac{8}{33}$$

as you have to remove the cases where Billy is called first and if he is called first there are $10!$ other ways to arrange the other students.

---

I know that the correct answer is $\frac{4}{15}$ though. Why doesn't simply subtracting $10!$ from the number of cases work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note: The original question didn't ask how to solve this problem - it asked why the given solution was wrong. My answer to that question is below in a comment, but I'm leaving this "answer" in case anyone is curious.*

---

When the first student is called, there are $10$ equally likely possibilities. With probability $\frac{2}{10}$, then, the first student is Annika or Catherine, and not one of the other 8 students present. In such a case, Billy is not called first. With probability $\frac{4}{5}$, none of the triplets is called first, and thereafter, any of the three is equally likely to be called first. As a result, the overall chance Billy is called first is $\frac{4}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{3}=\frac{4}{15}$. No elaborate counting needed.

Comment: Yes, that is the how I got the correct answer as $\frac{4}{15}$. I would like to know the method in my post did not work though.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see what you were asking. With the restriction in place, there are not $11!$ equally likely events. There are $10*10!$ equally likely possibilities, so it's simply a wrong denominator.

Comment: How did you get 10*10! possibilities? Is it because you have 10 choices for the first person (not Billy) and then 10! ways to arrange the rest?

Comment: And this is an example of conditional probability, right? Because you are finding the probability of Billy being called before his sisters given that Billy cannot be called first?

Comment: Yes, that's how I got $10\cdot10!$. Is it an example of conditional probability? It can be thought of that way, but it's not how I thought of it. I simply observed that given the restriction, there were $10\cdot10!$ equally likely possibilities, and I divided. (Analogously, you could find the probability of choosing 3 in a random selection from the integers 1 through 6 by considering it as the probability of getting a 3 from the numbers 1 through 7 given that the 7 can't be chosen, but you probably wouldn't do that or need to.)